# iOS removeFromSuperview causes crash while drawRect running

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, subview, drawrect

I have a UIView (a subview of my main view) which is following my touch-point around on the screen.

This view is constantly being redrawn via drawRect, as it is moved. At certain times in the procedure (say it has been dragged over a trash-can), I wish to remove the sub-view by deleting my underlying data object and removing it from its superview.

The problem is that when my controller calls removeFromSuperview, I sometimes get a crash because the view is still busy redrawing itself in drawRect.

I've got round this in my controller by putting a small delay in before I tell the subview to remove itself from its superview. However, I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this? I don't like 'delays' in apps fix a sync issue.

**EDIT:** ViewController code for tracking object move...called from view's touchesMoved() via delegate...

```
-(void)objectMoved:(UITrackObjectView *)trackObject
                centerPoint:(CGPoint)centerPoint:
{
    [_objectController updateObjectPosition:centerPoint];
    [annotationObject setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

When the object is up for deletion...

```
-(void)removeObject:(UITrackObjectView*)trackObject
{
// CAUSES CRASH SOMETIMES IF VIEW STILL REDRAWING
//    [droppedObject removeFromSuperview];

    [_objectController removeObject:droppedObject];

// CALL THIS WAY TO 'FIX'
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedTest:) withObject: trackObject afterDelay:0.25];

}

-(void)delayedTest:(UITrackObjectView*) trackObject
{
    [trackObject removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The view does drawing because it is using CoreGraphics to do drawing and give feedback due to its position. Whilst I know drawRect is inefficient, I'm not in a position to do bitmaps as there is wire-frame drawing to be done.

Comment: I think you are calling redraw in the touch move() method this is not a good technique because every time you call redraw on a view. DrawRect requires that you use the CPU to create a new bitmap of your view contents for every frame, then that bitmap gets copied over to the GPU. This approach is very slow instead you should change the view.center according to your touch.center point then it will just update views center that a good technique.

Comment: You should not call drawRect() by yourself. Use setNeedsDisplay() instead.

Comment: Show the code for drawRect and the removal. Why do you need to use drawRect anyway, can the content not be cached?

Comment: See edits. As shown, I use setneedsDisplay. The view that is being dragged needs regular 'redraws'